# In python, how do I copy files into a directory and stop once that directory reaches a certain size

Tags: python, copy, directory

I am still very new to Python, but I am trying to create a program which will, among other things, copy the contents of a directory into a set of directories that will fit onto a disc (I have it set up the following variables to be the size capacities I want, and set up an input statement to say which one applies):

```
BluRayCap = 25018184499
DVDCap = 4617089843
CDCap = 681574400
```

So basically I want to copy the contents of a beginning directory into another directory, and as needed, create another directory in order for the contents to fit into discs.

I kind of hit a roadblock here.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [os.path.getsize](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.getsize) to get the size of a file, and you can use [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk) to walk a directory tree, so something like the following (I'll let you implement CreateOutputDirectory and CopyFileToDirectory):

```
current_destination = CreateOutputDirectory()
for root, folders, files in os.walk(input_directory):
   for file in files:
       file_size = os.path.getsize(file)
       if os.path.getsize(current_destination) + file_size > limit:
          current_destination = CreateOutputDirectory()
       CopyFileToDirectory(root, file, current_destination)
```

Also, you may find the [Python Search](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/eoonlmlffmpfafcjmkenefnikdhnkgmk) extension for Chrome helpful for looking up this documentation.

Comment: That sounds like what I need.  I'll have to work on implementing those two functions, but now I have a more solid direction.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Michael Aaron Safyan's answer is good.

Besides, you can use **shutil** module to `CreateOutputDirectory` and `CopyFileToDirectory`